# Can I achieve type equivalency between uint_fast64_t and unsigned long long?

Tags: c++, unsigned-long-long-int

I have a large codebase that contains matrix-related code using uint_fast64_t as an index type. To make use of [GMM](http://download.gna.org/getfem/html/homepage/gmm/) as a solver backend, I need to convert (cast!) vectors from:

```
std::vector<uint_fast64_t, std::allocator<uint_fast64_t>>
```

to GMMs internal format

```
std::vector<unsigned long long, std::allocator<unsigned long long>>
```

Under MSVC2012, uint_fast64_t is typedef'd to unsigned long long, so both expressions are "the same".

I am well aware that they are, in fact, NOT the same type, as unsigned long long may be exactly 64bits long (long) (as it is implementation defined) and uint_fast64_t is at least 64bits long. ( --no-haters ;) )

Sadly, GCC4.7 and Clang 3.4 known uint_fast64_t as an internal type, making any type of cast impossible.

Additionally it seems that at some point, clang interprets uint_fast64_t as unsigned long - making it even more incompatible to the unsigned long long definition.

Which ways do you see out of my misery?

Is my only option replacing the unsigned long long in GMMs Code by hand?

Comment: Well, you can always do `*reinterpret_cast<A*>(&b)`. If you are certain the underlying types are the same, and you turn off strict aliasing checks in your compiler, it should work.

Comment: You can try to use `sizeof()` and check if both are the same size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a not-really-portable, but working solution:

```
static_assert(sizeof(uint_fast64_t) == sizeof(unsigned long long), "This code relies on equivalence of uint_fast64_t and unsigned long long");

std::vector<uint_fast64_t, std::allocator<uint_fast64_t>> src;

std::vector<unsigned long long, std::allocator<unsigned long long>> &after_cast = 
  *reinterpret_cast<std::vector<unsigned long long, std::allocator<unsigned long long>> *>(&src);
```

You have to compile this with strict type aliasing turned off (such as Clang's [`-fno-strict-aliasing`](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know_21.html)).

It relies on behaviour which is undefined in the standard, but by passing the appropriate compiler flag(s), you can actually make your compiler provide a consistent definition.

Comment: It seems like this is the only viable option. But the no-strict-aliasing option would introduce an overall performance penalty as some optimizations can not be performed. Or am I wrong? Is there really no other way?
I guess I have to patch the gmm sources.

Comment: Results of type aliasing (TA) are undefined in the standard precisely because relying on TA not happening enables optimisations, so if you need results of TA defined, you lose these optimisation opportunities. However, you should be able to put all these TA casts into one source file and pass `no-strict-aliasing` only for that file. From other files' perspective, the function is opaque and simply follows its prototype. If you refrain from accessing both the before-cast and after-cast references in the same code, you should be safe.

Answer (score 0):

`static_cast` should do the trick since they are all numeric types (providing that your fast64 ints are not using more than 64-bits).

```
unsigned long long convert_to_ull(uint_fast64_t i)
{
    return static_cast<unsigned long long>(i);
}


std::vector<uint_fast64_t> origData;
// fill in origData
std::vector<unsigned long long> data;
data.reserve(origData.size());
std::transform(origData.begin(), origData.end(), data.begin(), convert_to_ull);
```

Comment: I believe the OP's idea was to typecast the data in place, not create a copy.

Comment: Agreed, but there is not a portable way to do the cast in place.  This is the simplest portable method for obtaining the data he needs to send to the library he is trying to use.

Comment: It would kill performance. Still, you're 100% correct it's the only portable way.

Comment: Since performance and even worse, memory consumption is a criticial issue, this will not work for me :(

Comment: @ThE_-_BliZZarD which leaves you with either modifying your code to use the types the library expects, or using non-portable methods to achieve the same ends.